# Homebrew doesn't install GCC correctly

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, homebrew

I recently upgraded xcode command line tools to version 2384. After this I decided to reinstall gcc which was installed with homebrew. Installation completed with no errors but when I tried to compile a simple code with iostream library, it gave an error saying:

`/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory`

Later, I checked the library folder and there were multiple files missing such as assert.h. I want to ask is there any way to fix this other than installing every file one by one? I already tried updating homebrew and xcode command line tools.

Comment: I have the same problem as you do but still havent found a solution. If you did find one, please share it here with us. Thanks.